# Angular Parameter $routeParams and http.get params method didn't worked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to build a blog website using only front-end. My blog data is in an API. I have already build the blog feeds where list of different blogs are shown using AngularJS get method. But for the detailed view of the blog, I need to a single blog data result from the API.

I have already tried using `$routeParams` option. But it didn't work. My blog API has id parameter which return the blog data of the specific blog ID.

`blogdetail.html` (Template)

```
<div>
  <div><h1>Blog Details</h1></div>

  <div ng-repeat="xr in blog">
    {{xr.BLOGID}}
    
  <div>
</div>
```

`blogController.js` (Controller)

```
'use strict';
app.controller('blogController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('http://example.com/api/blog/', {
        params: {id: $routeParams.id}
    })
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.blog = res.data;
        }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR:", response);
    });
}]);
```

Route Provider of blog detail part of the website:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/Blog/:id", {
        controller : "blogController" ,
        templateUrl : "views/BlogDetail.html"
    })
```

This was the error I was getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: ` ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams)`
Here you request only scope and http, you are missing routeParams. That's why it does not get passed to the function.

Comment: As a side note: if you are just building this now, why would you use AngularJs? AngularJs has long since been discontinued in favour of Angular 2+. I'd strongly recommend switching to Angular as early as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to add all parameters in the array before the function which are needed in the function, otherwise they are not defined.

the issue is here `['$scope','$http', function`

```
'use strict';
    app.controller('blogController', ['$scope','$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $http.get('http://example.com/api/blog/', {
            params: {id: $routeParams.id}
        })
           .then(function(res){
              $scope.blog = res.data;
            }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log("ERROR:", response);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: I tried the solution by including 'routeParams' but then the error was - Error - [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20routeParams%20%3C-%20blogController

Comment: $routeParams it should be

Comment: Thank You, Your solution really helped me to get the blog details view and also thank you for a prompt reply to the question.